# How to handle socket.io acknowledgement from service.ts to component.ts on emit success Angular 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, socket.io, mean-stack

When the client emits a new message to the server using socket.io, the server sends an acknowledgment of the newly created messageId with the callback fn(). I am able to log the messageId in the service.ts, but cannot figure out a way to "get" the messageId to the component .ts (in order to update the newly created message with an ID). with the way the code is set below, I get an angular error saying I cannot subscribe to this.appService.newMessage(), even though I am returning an Observable of the new message id with of(newMsgId) in service.ts. Pls lmk if I can add any more information to help

```
server.js
--------

socket.on('newStaffMessage', function (data, fn) {
    var msg = new Message({
      sender: data.senderId,
      content: { text: data.content.text, attachment: null },
      dateTime: new Date(),
    });

    msg.save((err, messageDoc) => {
      Conversation.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { _id: data.conversationId },
        {
          $push: { messages: messageDoc._id },
        },
        { new: true },
        function (err, convoDoc) {
          if (!err) {
            User.findById(data.senderId, function (err, userDoc) {
              const payload = {
                conversationId: convoDoc._id,
                _id: messageDoc._id,
                content: {
                  text: msg.content.text,
                  attachment: msg.content.attachment,
                },
                dateTime: msg.dateTime,
                sender: {
                  _id: userDoc._id,
                  firstName: userDoc.firstName,
                  lastNameInitial: userDoc.lastNameInitial,
                },
              };

              io.in(convoDoc._id).emit('newStaffMessage', payload);
              fn({messageId: messageDoc._id});
            });
          } else {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  });
```

```
service.ts
----------

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Observer, of } from 'rxjs';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AppService {
  private socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  newMessage(msg) {
    this.socket.emit('newStaffMessage', msg, (newMsgId) => {
      return of(newMsgId);
    });
  }
```

```
component.ts
------------
this.appService.newMessage(newMessage).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You should properly convert handling socket.io event with callback to `Observable`.

I'd suggest you two options here:

1) Leverage `Observable` constructor or `create` operator with given subscription function:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
...
newMessage(msg) {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    this.socket.emit('newStaffMessage', msg, (newMsgId) => {
      observer.next(newMsgId);
    });
  });
}
```

2) Use dedicated for such purposes RxJS [bindCallback](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/bindCallback) function:

```
import { bindCallback } from 'rxjs';

newMessage(msg) {
  return bindCallback(this.socket.emit)('newStaffMessage', msg);
}
```

Comment: #1 worked! I was using that to handle "socket.on" events but not for emit - thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: I was stucked for return callback in client side in angular and your solution has helped me , thanks !